# Error updating pip version on mac

Tags: shell, pip

While updating pip on mac using the command 
`pip install --upgrade pip` 
 I am getting the following error 
 
 [image]

What should I do?

Comment: Try sudo. Its a permission denied error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to run it with sudo.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: yes, it helped. But I am unable to install tweepy using command `sudo pip install tweepy`
Error - OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-7ODKCm-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'

Comment: $ sudo pip install tweepy
Collecting tweepy
  Downloading tweepy-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting oauthlib>=0.6.2 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1->tweepy)
  Downloading oauthlib-2.0.1.tar.gz (122kB)
    100% 133kB 1.6MB/s 
Installing collected packages: oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, tweepy
  Running setup.py install for oauthlib ... done
Successfully installed oauthlib-2.0.1 requests-oauthlib-0.7.0 tweepy-3.5.0

Comment: ls -al /tmp ? This should symlink to /private/tmp. If the tmp doesn't exist in /private, just create it and retry